# set up a log in flow for our instance

Tags: apex, visualforce, flow

Is there anyway to have a login-flow only run every 30 days? We want to display a security message, but don't want it to display every time they log in as this may annoy users.

As , Is a class with each time field update value can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've wrote a blog post on this.  Essentially the same thing, except you would want to change the date field logic to be for 30 days instead of when you 'change' your security message as the post is setup for.  The best way to do this in a Flow would be to make the calculations on the actual user record instead of using a Flow's formula - just easier to maintain and validate its working correctly.

There shouldn't be any apex needed if you follow this post:

http://salesforcesidekick.com/2015/04/01/have-community-users-agree-to-terms-and-conditions/

---

EDIT:

Before we get into the Flow, you need to create TWO fields:
**Security Message Last Accepted** DATE FIELD 
and 
**Days Since Security Message Last Accepted** FORMULA FIELD
Formula = (TODAY () - **Security Message Last Accepted**)

So, you would start out:

Fast Lookup [Find User]
Fields to bring in **Security Message Last Accepted**

----> Decision ---->

You would change the "Yes - Login" criteria to:
User's **Days Since Security Message Last Accepted** LESS THAN #VALUE 30

The rest of the Flow would be the same, just changing your Security Message instead of the Terms and Conditions.

Comment: I have understand the scenario but can you please let me know how to implement the scenario of datafield compare as how to add +30 days and check.

Comment: See the update in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correction.. You want a message to display when a user views a record within xx days.

If so then you need to store this acknowledgment in a separate custom object record.

During the flow execution you want to invoke apex to check and see if the current users has a matching acknowledgment for that flow record.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=vpm_designer_elements_apex.htm&language=en_US

If the acknowledgement record doesn't exist then display your screen element with button which updates / creates the required acknowledgement record.

If the acknowledgement does exist just continue.